# Unity doesn't update object transform.position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics, game-development

I'm working on a little 2d game where you control a planet to dodge incoming asteroids. I'm implementing gravity in the following manner:

```
public class Gravity : MonoBehaviour
{
 Rigidbody2D rb;

 Vector2 lookDirection;

 float lookAngle;

 [Header ("Gravity")]
 
 // Distance where gravity works
 [Range(0.0f, 1000.0f)]
 public float maxGravDist = 150.0f;
 
 // Gravity force
 [Range(0.0f, 1000.0f)]
 public float maxGravity = 150.0f;
 
 // Your planet
 public GameObject planet;

 void Start()
 {
     rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
 }

 void Update()
 {   
     // Distance to the planet
     float dist = Vector3.Distance(planet.transform.position, transform.position);

     // Gravity
     Vector3 v = planet.transform.position - transform.position;
     rb.AddForce(v.normalized * (1.0f - dist / maxGravDist) * maxGravity);

     // Rotating to the planet
     lookDirection = planet.transform.position - transform.position;
     lookAngle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDirection.y, lookDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

     transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, lookAngle);  
 }
}
```

The problem is that the asteroids are attracted to the initial spawn point of the planet (0,0), it doesn't update in real time with the movement of the planet. So if I move the planet to the corner of the screen, the asteroids are still attracted to the centre of it.

When I use Debug.Log for each value all change except for planet.transform.position that stays at 0,0,0 even after moving it.

Is it a problem with the rigidbody of the planet? Any settings? I'm a bit lost.

Is there a way to solve this?

Thank you very much and excuse any flagrant errors!

Comment: this `1.0f - dist / maxGravDist` = `1.0f - 150 / 150` = 0 so you might not be adding any force?

Comment: But if I'm not adding any force how are the asteroids still moving?

Comment: Hey, you might want to check what gameobject you have assigned to the `planet` field. Maybe look at the scene hierarchy and check if the planet itself is a child of some stationary gameobject.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay it is actually `1 - dist / maxGravDist` = `1 - ? / 150` != `0` except the `?` is exactly `150` ;)

Comment: yeah, 150 is the default value, so if there were no values in the editor that would be the case. That was my point. Thanks :)

Comment: @rustyBucketBay no I understand your point :) but my point is you are wrong ^^ `dist` is the runtime distance between the objects and has no default value of `150` in the Inspector ;)

Comment: oh you are very right, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because the asteroids were dynamically spanwed from a prefab, they weren't a gameobject, the planet selected on the gameobject variable on the script was the prefab, not the real gameobject on the scene. I had to add this line to my spawner script

```
if (interval > random) {
 
GameObject newAsteroid = Instantiate(asteroidPrefab,
GetRandomPosition(), Quaternion.identity);
 
newAsteroid.GetComponent<Gravity>().planet = planet;

}
```

and at the top in your variables add

```
public GameObject planet;
```

add in your spawner script in the editor, drag and drop your planet
gameobject.

This fixed the issue.